# How do I use the Google Docs editor in my Yii application?

Tags: php, yii, google-drive-api, yii-extensions

I know it seems there are lots of similar questions but unfortunately, none of the answers provided seem satisfactory (at least for the questions I've read).

I'm interested in using the Google drive Word processor and spreadsheet app within my Yii application. I want to know:

1) If this is even possible with the SDK

2) How the integration is done

3) if there's an online resource I can lookup for guidance

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed it but you wont have control over it.
You can read its data with the google document list api

Comment: Thanks. You've answered my first question. Now to the second and third questions...

Comment: Look at the api docs.